# Layout of embedded video on page

Tags: html, video, format, embed, paragraph

I'm trying to place an embedded video on a page, with text above and below it. At the moment, the text appears to the side of the video, as is visible in the below image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmgMy.png)

The code is:

```
<p>Here is a quick "how to" video to show you how it works:</p>
<p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/I6cynOuqJ3E" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>
<p> </p>
<p>If you have any questions or suggestions, please get in touch at <a href="mailto:workvoicepay@unitetheunion.org" title="workvoicepay@unitetheunion.org">workvoicepay@unitetheunion.org</a></p>
```

I've tried using the following tags to try to fix it (with embedded video at top, and 'If you have any question...' as bottom):

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">stuff goes here</div>
  <div class="bottom">more stuff</div>
```

And this tag after the embedded video:

```
<p class="clear">
```

However neither have had any effect.

Can anybody help?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ct0omerw/ works fine, the problem from the framework, if you are using bootstrap go with flex.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Umbraco 10.7.0. to build this. Are you saying the problem is with Umbraco? Is there a workaround you could suggest, i.e. a way I could adjust the code to get around the issue with the framework.

Comment: I don't mean the issue is with Umbraco or any other framework. It could be related to the code organization, the use of CSS, missing end tags, etc.

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about addressing that, or identifying what the issue is?